# I compiled samba 3.6.4 on Solaris 9, and can't get smbd to run

Tags: solaris, samba, oracle

I compiled the latest release of samba on a Solaris 5.9 system to address [CVE-2012-1182](https://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2012-1182), and I'm getting this result when I run smbd.

```
fs17151# ./smbd -i
smbd version 3.6.4 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
===============================================================
INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 6 in pid 6959 (3.6.4)
Please read the Trouble-Shooting section of the Samba3-HOWTO

From: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba3-HOWTO.pdf
===============================================================
PANIC (pid 6959): internal error
unable to produce a stack trace on this platform
dumping core in /var/adm/samba/cores/smbd
Abort
```

Google results aren't helping me much with my problem, and the [Samba3-HOWTO.pdf](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba3-HOWTO.pdf) seems to assume smbd is running for all of its troubleshooting examples. Does anyone know what can cause these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run into the crash bug when setting log level = 3?

You should talk to the nice guys at samba for support. Install gdb, run smbd in gdb and send them a backtrace along with your smb.conf

Or install 3.6.5, or patch 3.6.4

Have a look here http://www.samba.org/